# How to create 2 folders inside a subfolder using wix

Tags: wix, wix3.6

just started to embrace WIX and I am trying to create a setup program for my c# wpf app.

I want to have 2 folders created within a subfolder I created inside the programdata folder.

The following code will only create 1 folder 'data' but not 'log'.

What am i doing wrong please?

Thanks

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
<Product Id="*" Name="EmptyFolderExample" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="WixExamples" UpgradeCode="b9f6f617-7d4c-4b9a-a165-24bd869ce1e9">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
    <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes" />

    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="EmptyFolderExample" Level="1">
        <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
    </Feature>
</Product>

<Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
        <Directory Id="CommonAppDataFolder">
    <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="InformedWorker">
      <Directory Id="EmptyDataFolderDir" Name="Data" />
      <Directory Id="EmptyLogFolderDir" Name="Log" />
    </Directory>
        </Directory>
    </Directory>
</Fragment>



<Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="EmptyDataFolderDir">
  <Component Id="CMP_MyEmptyDataDir"
         Guid="85DAD4AE-6404-4A40-B713-43538091B9D3"
         KeyPath="yes">
    <CreateFolder />
  </Component>
</ComponentGroup>
</Fragment>

<Fragment>
<ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents2" Directory="EmptyLogFolderDir">
  <Component Id="CMP_MyEmptyLogDir"
    Guid="a4594ec9-3101-4627-8ee7-d60d0a9b1f63"
    KeyPath="yes">
    <CreateFolder />
  </Component>
 </ComponentGroup>
</Fragment>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a component with Directory="EmptyLogFolderDir", the same as you did for the data.

Comment: hi, yes I had done that. It did not appear in my original question as the indentation was wrong. Corrected/edited it now. But this did not work for me :(

Comment: Add that <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents2" /> under feature.

Comment: The accepted answer includes the last comment by @ArkadySitnitsky.
Thanx!